# UIPageController: Turning the page forward then backward quickly only updates the first page

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have the class `SliderPgaeViewController: UIPageViewController` with scroll transition style as follows:

```
class SliderPgaeViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, PlayerUpdatePageControllerDelegate {


var lastPendingIndex: Int = 0
var sliderPageDelegate: SliderPageDelegate? = nil
let playerManager = PlayerManager.getInstance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    setViewControllers([createViewController(index: playerManager.getCurrentIndex())!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    lastPendingIndex = playerManager.getCurrentIndex()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return playerManager.getSongsCount()
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let vc = viewController as? PlayerImageViewController {
        if (vc.index == 0){
            return nil
        }
        return createViewController(index: vc.index! - 1)
    }
    return nil

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let vc = viewController as? PlayerImageViewController {
        if (vc.index == playerManager.getSongsCount() - 1){
            return nil
        }
        return createViewController(index: vc.index! + 1)
    }
    return nil
}


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]){
    if let vc = pendingViewControllers[0] as? PlayerImageViewController {
        self.lastPendingIndex = vc.index!
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    print("before completion : \(self.lastPendingIndex)")
    if(completed){
        print("completed : \(self.lastPendingIndex)")
        if (viewControllers?.first as? PlayerImageViewController) != nil {
            sliderPageDelegate?.updateSong(index: self.lastPendingIndex, dir: 0)
        }
    }
}

private func createViewController(index i: Int) -> UIViewController?{
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerImageController") as! PlayerImageViewController
    vc.index = i
    vc.image = playerManager.getSong(index: i).image
    return vc
}
...
```

I am using this page controller to display the thumbnail of a song in a music player. And when the user turn a page the player changes the song playing by calling `sliderPageDelegate?.updateSong(index: self.lastPendingIndex, dir: 0)` in `pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],transitionCompleted completed: Bool)`

When I'm turning the page forward and then immediately backward, the page is turning correctly (first forward then backward); however, `sliderPageDelegate?.updateSong(index: self.lastPendingIndex, dir: 0)` is only being called in the forward direction.

So, if we have list of songs `(A, B, C, ...)` and we are currently at song `A`. When the user swipes forward, the thumbnail changes to `B's` thumbnail and the player updates the song to `B`. However, if the forward swipe was followed by a backward swipe quickly, then the thumbnail changes to `A` but the song remains `B`

**Update:**

if `A` has `index = 0` and `B` has `index = 1`, moving `A->B->A` quickly will print the following:

```
before completion : 1
before completion : 1
completed : 1
```

Comment: Just curious, is the UIPageViewController delegate actually reaching the event that passes `completed = true` to the delegate function that updates the song? Sounds too simple, but then again every time I expect something to happen and it doesn't that's my first check (E.g. "Did the event wrapping the function actually fire that condition?").

Comment: @Archdoog, check the update. I think it answers your question

Comment: In your `viewControllerBerfore` and `viewControllerAfter` code you call an `if let vc = viewController as? PlayerImageViewController` Are you certain that each vc is a `PlayerImageViewController`?

Comment: @MrGreen does placing all of the song-updating logic in the method that updates the thumbnail have any effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `PageControllerDelegate` in your code and introduce two new methods. Then implement these delegates in your `UIPageViewController` class and then in `PlayerImageViewController` class invoke both methods in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`. Now remove you `didFinishAnimation` method and write that code in `viewControllerIsBeingDisplay`.

For deeper knowledge review this code.

```
class PlayerImageViewController: UIViewController {
    var index: Int?
    var image: UIImage?
    weak var delegate: PageControllerDelegate?


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if let del = self.delegate {
            del.viewControllerIsBeingHide(self)
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let del = self.delegate {
            del.viewControllerIsBeingDisplay(self)
        }
    }
}
protocol SliderPageDelegate {
    func updateSong(index: Int, dir: Int)
}
protocol PageControllerDelegate {
    func viewControllerIsBeingHide(_ viewController: PlayerImageViewController)
    func viewControllerIsBeingDisplay(_ viewController: PlayerImageViewController)
}
class SliderPgaeViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, PageControllerDelegate {


    var lastPendingIndex: Int = 0
    var sliderPageDelegate: SliderPageDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        setViewControllers([createViewController(index: playerManager.getCurrentIndex())!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        lastPendingIndex = playerManager.getCurrentIndex()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return playerManager.getSongsCount()
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let vc = viewController as? PlayerImageViewController {
            if (vc.index == 0){
                return nil
            }
            return createViewController(index: vc.index! - 1)
        }
        return nil

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let vc = viewController as? PlayerImageViewController {
            if (vc.index == playerManager.getSongsCount() - 1){
                return nil
            }
            return createViewController(index: vc.index! + 1)
        }
        return nil
    }


    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]){
        if let vc = pendingViewControllers[0] as? PlayerImageViewController {
            self.lastPendingIndex = vc.index!
        }
    }


    private func createViewController(index i: Int) -> UIViewController?{
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerImageController") as! PlayerImageViewController
        vc.index = i
        vc.delegate = self
//        vc.image = playerManager.getSong(index: i).image //Commented becoz i do not have this file
        return vc
    }
    var previousVCIndex = 0

    func viewControllerIsBeingHide(_ viewController: PlayerImageViewController) {
        previousVCIndex = viewController.index!
    }
    func viewControllerIsBeingDisplay(_ viewController: PlayerImageViewController) {
        if let del = sliderPageDelegate {
            del.updateSong(index: previousVCIndex, dir: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed my issue. But the logic of `previousVCIndex` is not correct. I used the `viewController.index` in `viewControllerIsBeingDisplay` and didn't use `viewControllerIsBeingHide` at all.

Comment: I thought you might to share some information from previous screen to next one thats why i use this `previousVCIndex` logic.